# Did early prophets use to offer salah?

Tags: salat, prophets

Did early prophets use to offer salah?  As salah was made farz when Muhammed (pbuh) was there.  Did early prophets use to recite Quran in their salah?

Answer (score 1):

The Children of Isra'il were also obliged to establish the salah and give the zakah 2:43, 2:83, 3:43, 19:31 but surely those previous nations wouldn't be reciting this Qu'ran, since it wasn't revealed to them.